# Unset Specific Shipping Rate When Free Shipping Rate is Available for 2 Shipping zones

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I found this code:

```
/**
 * @snippet       Hide one shipping rate when Free Shipping is available
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 6
 * @community     https://businessbloomer.com/club/
 */
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_in_zone', 9999, 2 );
   
function bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_in_zone( $rates, $package ) {
   // Only unset rates if free_shipping is available
   if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:8'] ) ) {
      unset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] );
   }     
   return $rates;
}
```

I can only use this to add one free shipping and one flat rate, I want to use this code for 2 free shipping and 2 flat rates because I have 2 Shipping zones. How can it be done?

I used that code and it worked for one shipping zone, but I need it to work for .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code work for multiple shipping zones, first you need to get all involved shipping rates IDs for each shipping zone, then set them in the array below:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 9999, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    // Here below define the related shipping methods rate IDs for each shipping zone
    $shipping_data = array(
        array('free' => 'free_shipping:8',  'flat' => 'flat_rate:1'), // first zone
        array('free' => 'free_shipping:10', 'flat' => 'flat_rate:5'), // other zone
    );

    // Loop through shipping data array
    foreach ( $shipping_data as $data_zone ) {
        if ( isset($rates[$data_zone['free']],$rates[$data_zone['flat']]) ) {
            unset($rates[$data_zone['flat']]);
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

**Important:** You will have to empty your cart to refresh shipping methods cache.

Comment: Thank you so much tested it, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the function to loop through each shipping zone and check if free shipping is available in that zone:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_in_zones', 9999, 2 );

function bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_in_zones( $rates, $package ) {
    // Get all shipping zones
    $zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();

    foreach ( $zones as $zone ) {
        // Get the zone ID
        $zone_id = $zone['zone_id'];

        // Check if free shipping is available in the current zone
        if ( isset( $rates["free_shipping:$zone_id"] ) ) {
            // Unset flat rates for the current zone
            unset( $rates["flat_rate:$zone_id"] );
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

This code will loop through all shipping zones and unset the flat rate for each zone where free shipping is available.